# Marketplace title difference wp7 and wp8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to create wp7 and wp8 versions of my app, but I'm confused about Marketplace (Windows Store) title.

For WP7:
 
I use Windows 7 + VS2010 + WP7.1 SDK, and what I have:
When I open Marketplace Test Kit I need to add Marketplace title `200*200 pixels`. 
I also found this article: [Creating Windows Phone 7 Application 
and Marketplace Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/gg317447.aspx), where Marketplace title also `200*200 pixels`.

For WP8:
I use Windows 8 + VS2012 + WP8 SDK, and what I have:
When I open Windows Store Test Kit I need to add Windows Phone Store app image `300*300 pixels`. 
I also found this article: [App submission requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), where Windows Phone Store app image also `300*300 pixels`.

My question is: 
 Why it's happens? 
 Why I need to add same image with different size for each version of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 introduced higher resolution screens (768x1280 and 720x1280). This is up to 1.6x pixel count of WP7.

So to make sure the images look good on the higher resolution phones, a higher resolution image is required for your icons.